# ColdFusion JVM: strange memory behaviour

Tags: java, coldfusion, garbage-collection, jvm, jconsole

Since last month, we got a problem on our company's server (Win2008ServerStd + IIS7 + CF enterprise 9.0.1 (hotfix2)).

I used jConsole to monitor the Coldfusion JVM (1.6.0_24) activity and here's what I see:

[image: Curve1]

[image: Curve2]

Notice that strange "curve" between 14:10 and 14:15 ! What is that?

Obviously it's not a standard behaviour, when it happens, my applications hang for 30 to 70 seconds!

Do you know what can cause that memory issue? It seems like GC does not run correctly, or hangs itself.

I don't expect a flash-answer, I wonder there can be a lot of root problems causing that but.... where can I start investigating?

Comment: Any updates? Have you figured it out yet?

Comment: No..... :-( It could be related to IIS Application Pool recycling, or jdbc driver hanging. Not yet sure. I'll keep this question updated.

Comment: You could be running into the "max processor" problem I found here: http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/11/4/iis7.constrain.simultaneous.requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cfstat, perfmon, fusionreactor, or cf perfomance monitor take a look at running requests and queued duing your problem. What you will likely see is running requests climbing past the setting of the simultaneous requests (in the cf admin). Then the requests will start to queue. Eventually the queue will clear out (if your server is recovering on it's own).

This sort of thing can be caused by a number of things. For example, if your DB server slows down or has an issue, if your network has a problem, or if network ports are resyncing, if your disks have I/O problems etc.

My guess is that you will drive yourself batty trying to figure this out by monitoring your heap. See if you can watch one of the monitors for some specific scripts that might be the culprit.

The other comment (about some indexing agents) is also a possibility. A flurry of indexing can definitely cause behavior. If that's the case, you might take a look at the simultaneous request settings. If it is set at the default you might have enough head room to increase it.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, Mark! Our big problem is that this behaviour happens in low traffic time frames, too. Our suspect is that there can be a problem in the communication between IIS7 and CF9. We also never saw a lot of simultaneous requests together, to increase that parameter.

Comment: If it is CF and IIS you would likely see some errors in the server.log file. You could try disabling windows firewall temporarily. The one thing that would make me wonder about your hypothesis is the randomness of it. If you were being blocked somehow it would be more predictable.

Answer (score 1):

It could have been a spider creating lots and lots of sessions as it crawled the site which would eat up memory for a period of time.  Once the spider stopped crawling those sessions would time out and be garbage collected.

I would compare your HTTP server logs w/ the JVM logs.  Compare that time frame and see if there are a lot of requests from a search engine spider (Googlebot, msnbot, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Fabio,
Same kind of issue I have couple of month ago where I was getting spike on regular interval and server eating up arround 50% of CPU usage. I wrote full story below URL 
http://www.isummation.com/blog/strange-coldfusion-issue-jrun-eating-up-to-50-of-cpu/
which may help you (Sorry for so long).

I found that client variables storing in registry was causing issue and I am able to catch with help of VisualVM where I first find out thread causing issue and looking into trace of exactly find solution.

Comment: thank you a lot for your answer. Only one thing: you say "looking into trace of exactly find solution". How can I do the same? How can I look the stack trace in a given time frame?

Comment: in addition: as you can see from the jconsole chart, when the jvm is going crazy, the cpu usage falls near zero level. :)

Comment: Using jTop you may able to find out which thread eating up more CPU usage and try VisualVm thread inspector plugin which will help you know about thread trace log.
If you want to configure coldfusion with VISUALVM below post will help you on this.
http://www.isummation.com/blog/configure-coldfusion-with-visualvm/

Just go through post in answer where I mention how do I get everything.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that's really odd IMO is the sudden spike to having so many threads.  Capture a thread dump on a regular basis (jstack, etc.. are your friends) and then correlate those thread dumps to your monitoring where it shows the spike.

The root problem will become more obvious once you understand what all the extra threads are doing.  Perhaps it's more threads handling transactions, but it might be something else entirely.